# 2010 Ford Fusion CARB certification

Tags: ford, emissions, fusion

I have a 2010 Ford Fusion that I will be bringing from Texas to California. Will I need to do any modifications to be CARB certified?

Answer (score 1):

If your vehicle [does not have CA emissions](https://www.dmv.ca.gov/portal/dmv/?1dmy&urile=wcm:path:/dmv_content_en/dmv/pubs/brochures/fast_facts/ffvr29), you won't be able to register the vehicle in CA. There are a few exceptions:

- Obtained as part of a divorce, inheritance, or legal separation settlement.
- Purchased to replace your California-registered vehicle that was stolen while you were using the vehicle out-of-state.
- Purchased to replace your California-registered vehicle that was destroyed or made inoperative beyond reasonable repair while you were using the vehicle out of state.
- An emergency vehicle, pursuant to California Vehicle Code § §27156.2 and 27156.3.
- Registered by you in the state of your last active military service outside California.
- A street motorcycle or motor-driven cycle year model 2005 and older, with an engine less than 50 cubic centimeters (cc) displacement. Beginning January 1, 2006, street motorcycles and motor-driven cycles year model 2006 and newer, with engines less than 50 cc displacement, require an emission label certifying them to meet U.S. Environmental Protection Agency emission regulations, and may be registered regardless of mileage.

To figure out if your vehicle is CARB compliant, the emissions sticker should be under the hood and look something like this:
[image]

Mind you, this doesn't apply to you if you are Military and are a resident of another state. CA has a lot of other strange rules, so best to read up on them at their website (found through the link above).